# Strange jQuery behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that `$("#SendingType").val(2)` sets the value of the select to 2.

So, why does this goes to else??

```
$(function () {
    $("#calculate").click(function () {
        var result = $("#SendingType").val();
        var day1 = eval(result) + 3;
        var day2 = eval(result) + 10;
        var day3 = eval(result) + 2;
        if ($("#SendingType").val(2)) {
            $("#result").text(day1 + " and " + day2 + " days.");
        } else {
            $("#result").text(day1 + " and " + day3 + " days.");
        }
    });
});
```

I am aware that this is not correct way to code `if` statement.

**SOLVED**: Thank you Jason and Juhana. The code does not go to else, I thought it would because the value of the select influences the if result. Always if but with different results because of the new select value.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5bmhr/)

Comment: It's not. It's setting the value to 2 after the calculation, maybe that's confusing you?

Comment: Actually use '$("#SendingType").val() == 2' to check the condition?

Comment: @bfavaretto, yes, it sets the value but `$("#result").text` is different depending on selected.

Comment: Side note: `eval()` is totally unnecessary here. Use `parseInt( result, 10 )` instead.

Comment: @Juhana, yes, thank you. I just simplified my code to this example and  left it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks to me like it runs the `true` branch regardless:

http://jsfiddle.net/tMwRV/

Which makes sense. You are setting the value to `2`, not checking the value. The statement `$("#SendingType").val(2)` returns a jQuery object, which is "truthy".

Comment: How do you explain I get the content from the else?

Comment: I don't think you do. Look at my fiddle, it logs the output from the `true` branch for either option.

Comment: @Sergio Your original fiddle doesn't show content from the else branch. I get "5 and 12 days" which is the values of `day1` and `day2`.

Comment: @Juhana, Jason... sorry. `.text()` is being changed depending on the value of the select... so it changes value of day1-3 and always goes thru if, never else. This was a "no question".

Comment: @Sergio Yes, and this answer explains why. If I understand correctly what you're after you want `$("#SendingType").val("2"); if( result === "2" ) { ...` (the original value of the dropdown is in `result`).

Comment: @Juhana, yes. I am just tired and got too focused on the wrong thing. Time to go out and get some air.